# Make Dynamic Download link WGET friendly

Tags: file, dynamic, download, wget

I'm trying to make a PHP page which gets the latest version of my scripts and then initiates the download. Currently it is brower friendly but doesn't seem to be WGET friendly.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM downloads ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
        $name = $row['name'];

$pathToFile = '/home/phasec/PingEZ-Downloads/'.$name.'';

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=PingEZ-Latest.zip");
readfile($pathToFile);
```

It is meant to download a ZIP file, which it does when accessing via the web address in a browser. But I need it to be browser friendly AND WGET friendly for servers.

Comment: How is it not "wget friendly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ZIP file MIME-type is `application/zip`, though it should work fine with what you're specifying too.

I would also suggest adding a `Content-Length` header with the size of the file, the `filesize()` function should do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `readfile()` you could copy the file to a publicly accessible location and redirect the user there. That should satisfy both browser and `wget` conditions. I got the idea from this post:
[Use php's readfile() or redirect to display a image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050975/use-phps-readfile-or-redirect-to-display-a-image-file)

Comment: Yea I thought about doing this, though wanted to keep everything simple :) Thanks.